# windows API : Pass mouse click through windows

Tags: c++, windows, flutter, winapi, desktop-application

I'm working on an on-screen Annotation flutter desktop app where I want to let the mouse click pass through to the window beneath my window. Now Basically I know that there is a win32api window that hosting the flutter content.

Also, I was able to find a way by using `SetWindowLong` and applying `GWL_EXSTYLE` to my window.

```
int extendedStyleSettings = GetWindowLong(window,GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(window,GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyleSettings | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
```

The problem with this solution is I don't know how to restore mouse event on windows or keep it active on my window because I can't do anything I can't click on the border, caption bar, system menu, or minimize/maximize/close buttons.
It just completely disables my window

Comment: I think handling `WM_NCHITTEST` message and returning `HTNOWHERE` when cursor is at desired area should help.

Comment: Beware this is inconsistant with the *standard* windows look and feel... It is not easy to implement for a reason.

Comment: I feel that this question is missing a fair bit of crucial information in between *"I want to allow mouse input to go to the window underneath my window"* and "*I don't wont to allow mouse input to got to the window underneath my window"*. Can you fill in the gaps by explaining what you're ultimately after?

Comment: @IInspectable       ok, I want my app to be similar to epic pen I set up my app to take the fullscreen and make the background transparent so it look like the app only has the toolbar. in the epic pen when you use the pen you can't actually press on the desktop icon or other apps, but when you use the cursor you can press on desktop icons and other apps how I can apply the same functionality with win32api?

Comment: I suppose this functionality is exposed by the [InkCanvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas) type, though I haven't looked closely.